# Get original/unmodified request string via javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve the original request string for the last request / the site I am currently seeing in the browser.

I know that I can retrieve all kinds of strings via
`window.location.*` properties, but I can't be sure that those were not changed via the history APi via pushState etc. (without page refresh)

I could of course store the original string once at the beginning after the page is loaded, before doing things with the history API, but maybe there is already some way built in to get what I want?

Comment: try the `state` property of the history object to know if its changed .. see answer below @riesling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the `history.state`.

The value is `null` for most documents unless it has been altered by the **history API**.

So your javascript could check for

`if(history.state===null)
//do something`

Generally there is a `window.onpopstate` event fired on history changes via the API but browsers handle it differently .

See more about `window.onpopstate` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate).

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear if this is what you're asking but you could use either local or session storage to store the value and call it back each time the page is loaded/reloaded. Known as HTML5 storage: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: Ben -- I think OP is asking (and it's buried at the end) if something like this is "built-in" - that is, usable without manually shoving data into storage, like a window.location.history - which I do not believe is the case.